# SignalR java client hubConnection.on() method not trigger any method after receiving data

Tags: java, android, signalr, signalr.client

I use SignalR in my android app to receive real time data. When my "hubConnection.on()" method start it receive data successfully but inside this method it not allow me to use that data. Like when i write code like this :

```
   hubConnection = HubConnectionBuilder.create("http://www.example.com").build();

    hubConnection.start();

    hubConnection.on("ReceiveLocation", (lat, lng) -> {

        Log.i("dataCheck", "-> "+Double.parseDouble(lat));
        Log.i("dataCheck", "-> "+Double.parseDouble(lng));
        if(hubConnection.getConnectionState() == HubConnectionState.DISCONNECTED)
            hubConnection.start();

    }, String.class, String.class);
```

The this above case data receive successfully and also print in Log.

But when i try use this "lat" , "lng" variables, like i try to show a toast with "lat" value, data not receive this method and also toast not show on screen. Like i use code like this:

```
        hubConnection = HubConnectionBuilder.create("http://www.example.com").build();

    hubConnection.start();

    hubConnection.on("ReceiveLocation", (lat, lng) -> {


        Toast.makeText(OrderTrackingActivity.this, "->>>"+Double.parseDouble(lat), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        Log.i("dataCheck", "-> "+Double.parseDouble(lat));
        Log.i("dataCheck", "-> "+Double.parseDouble(lng));
        if(hubConnection.getConnectionState() == HubConnectionState.DISCONNECTED)
            hubConnection.start();

    }, String.class, String.class);
```

In this 2nd code the data not receive and toast not show. Please suggest me the possible solutions to solve this problem. I need to use this coming data.

Follow a suggestion i try to store the value of "lat", "lng" (variables of .on() funtion) into my own define variables and then pass these my variables to my function name "myFuntion" like this :

```
 hubConnection.on("ReceiveLocation", (lat, lng) -> {

        varbl1 = lat;
        varbl2 = lng;
    Log.i("dataCheck", "-> "+Double.parseDouble(lat));
    Log.i("dataCheck", "-> "+Double.parseDouble(lng));

    myFuntion(varbl1 , varbl2);

    if(hubConnection.getConnectionState() == HubConnectionState.DISCONNECTED)
        hubConnection.start();

}, String.class, String.class);
```

Then in "myFuntion" i Log the values and successfully values print but still when i use that values either show in Toast or do something else the signalR "hubConnection.on()" funtion stop working. Here is my "myFuntion" method code:

```
 public void myFuntion(String value, String value2){
   
    Toast.makeText(this, ""+value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

Comment: Have you tried assign the received variables to your variables before using them? Like `myLat = lat`

Comment: @Kiril1512 I try to give this variables to my function but it not work. Let me check by giving these variables values to my define variables.

Comment: @Kiril1512 please check my updated question from last, i use your suggestion but still i face the problem

Answer (score 1):

[**Call client methods from hub**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/java-client?view=aspnetcore-7.0#call-client-methods-from-hub)

Use hubConnection.on to define methods on the client that the hub can call. Define the methods **after building** but **before starting** the connection.

example:

```
hubConnection = HubConnectionBuilder.create("http://www.example.com").build();

hubConnection.on("ReceiveLocation", (lat, lng) -> {
    Log.i("dataCheck", "-> "+Double.parseDouble(lat));
    Log.i("dataCheck", "-> "+Double.parseDouble(lng));
    if(hubConnection.getConnectionState() == HubConnectionState.DISCONNECTED)
        hubConnection.start();

}, String.class, String.class);


hubConnection.start();
```

> **Note**:
> If you do not know the type of data sent from the server to the client, use **Object.class**.

Use this method if you want to toast or have changes in UI:

```
hubConnection.on("ReceiveLocation", (data) -> {
        this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, data.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                txtPath.setText(data.toString());
            }
        });
},Object.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

This Problem is because of the `UI Thread` not `Signalr`, you can try this code

```
            hubConnection.on("ReceiveTxt",(txt)-> {
            Activity activity = (Activity) context;
            activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "->>> :" + txt, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }, String.class);
```

If you are in an `Activity` use this

```
hubConnection.on("ReceiveTxt",(txt)-> {
        this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(this, "->>> :" + txt, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }, String.class);
```